# Add Hex characters in a file with python

Tags: python, hex

I would like to add a list of specific Hex characters at the first line of my file.

bin = "**420d0d0a010000000000000000000000**"

file1:

```
e300 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0002 0000
0040 0000 0073 6a00 0000 6400 6401 6c00
5a00 6400 6401 6c01 5a01 6400 6401 6c02
5a02 6400 6401 6c03 5a03 6400 6401 6c02
...
```

file2:

```
420d 0d0a 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
e300 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0002 0000
0040 0000 0073 6a00 0000 6400 6401 6c00
5a00 6400 6401 6c01 5a01 6400 6401 6c02
5a02 6400 6401 6c03 5a03 6400 6401 6c02
...
```

I would like to get the file2.

I tried that:

```
bin = "420d0d0a010000000000000000000000"

def change_hex():
    with open("file.txt") as f: 
        lines = f.readlines()

    lines[0] = f"{bin}\n"

    with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
        f.writelines(lines)
```

But it didn't work, I had this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 174: character maps to <undefined>
```

Maybe it's not the right thing to do?

Thanks in advance, have a good day.

Comment: Edit the question to explain "didn't work".

Comment: But precisely, I don't know why it didn't work, that's also why I'm asking for help.

Comment: Is this a hexdump or the actual file content? Also, please include the **full** traceback of the error.

Comment: Hex dump I think, I'm trying to modify a .pyc file

Comment: you probably need to open the file as binary, but it's difficult to know exactly what's  wrong

Comment: I tried this: (but it doesnt work):
https://pastebin.com/t9aHfRBa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open your files in binary mode and to convert the hex str to bytes using `bytes.fromhex`.

```py
header = bytes.fromhex("420d0d0a010000000000000000000000")

def change_hex():
    with open("file.txt", "rb") as f: 
        content = f.read()

    with open("file.txt", "wb") as f:
        f.write(header)
        f.write(content)
```

Comment: WOW, IT WORKS, thank you very much, thank you for taking the time to help me.
Have a good day !

<3

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are **replacing** the first line for your new line, but you need to **append** the new line to the beginning.

Just try replacing this line

```
lines[0] = f"{bin}\n"
```

For this

```
lines.insert(0,bin)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I got the same error: